# How do I allow relate multiple instances of the same object Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-database

I am new to: relational databases, SQL and Entity.  Please forgive me if I do not use the correct terminology.

What I am trying to do is relate the same row to another, twice.

IE:

Transaction has a many-to-many relationship with Item.

So I simply:

```
    internal static void AddItem(int itemID, Transaction transaction)
    {
        Item item = (from i in db.Items
                     where i.Id == itemID
                     select i).SingleOrDefault();

        transaction.Items.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The issue is that I can not add the same item twice (say if a person bought two of the same item).  I'm sure there is some obvious reason for this that is beyond me, but I don't know how this very-common database concept is normally handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may involve re-thinking the data model a bit.  Perhaps having a Purchase contain multiple Items isn't necessarily the way to go, even as it's defined as many to many in the relational model.  At this point the intermediate table maintaining that many-to-many relationship is itself becoming a business entity to be used and tracked.

A "PurchaseItem" is now a single instance of an Item involved in a Purchase, and has its own data and relevance apart from the Item.  It's a line item on a given purchase, independent and unique to itself, and merely refers back to the Item that's being purchased.  Thus, a Purchase would need a list of PurchaseItems rather than a list of Items.

Comment: I had a feeling that an intermediate table might be the correct correct way to do this, but I wasn't sure.  Thanks for the fast answer.